# first_open not getting logged

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I was analysing my firebase events exported data into biqquery.

My finding are  is that when a user opens the app after reinstalling it. The user_psuedo_id and user_first_touch_timestamp changes but the event "first_open" does not get logged again.

In the following document it is mentioned that it get logged again.
Link to doc: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en

Can someone please help me understand the reason for it?

Thank You